# Get the host name with dot using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

**Input:**

```
This script may take a while to run, especially on a busy podmaster.
Generating Syslog TopN list on node for last 3 hours.

        Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59
            Rank       Number of Alerts Host
            ----       ---------------- ----
        1       3124        aaa.ab.com
        2       2294        bbb
        3       2157        ccc
        4       832     ddd
        5       816     eee

Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 01:00:00 and 01:59:59
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       5495        fff
        2       2625        ggg
        3       998     hhh
        4       752     iii
        5       741     jjj

Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 00:00:00 and 00:59:59
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       2747        kkk
        2       876     lll
        3       780     mmm
        4       724     nnn
        5       309     ooo
```

I have used the below regular expression to match this format.

```
\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+([\w]+)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+([\w]+)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+([\w]+)
```

the output for above expression is

```
$2 = aaa.ab.com
$4 = fff
$5 = kkk
```

But I need the regular expression to match the ranks rank 1 separately.

```
Example output:
$2 = aaa.ab.com 
$4 = fff
$5 = kkk
```

we have to write a regex to match both ab.com and ab.com not present cases.
Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Your are not a man of many words when it comes to problem description, and expected output looks the same as the one you achieved. Could you expand on what is the problem?

Comment: So the only thing you want is to make .com optinal?

Comment: some cases .com will be there, some other case it won't. we have to  write regex for both cases to satisfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ab[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ab[\.]com)?)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)\s+((?:\w+)(?:[\.]ab[\.]com)?)
```